# Mac OS X bash: uninstall all apache and PHP occurences

Tags: mac, bash, php, apache-http-server, uninstall

How do I find all installed apache and PHP occurences on a Mac OS X system in bash and uninstall them?

My motivation:
I've managed to install multiple apache and PHP packages (I believe it's called packages in Unix terms, correct?) at some point, and I'ld like to start out fresh again, without completely re-installing Mac OS X again.

Also, I'ld like to install suPHP along with apache this time, and I believe I need to compile apache with some additional stuff for that. But that is a challenge I'll deal with later, and probably ask a question about then. :)

Thank you in advance for your info.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's been ~9 months since you asked this question, very likely you've already learned how to do this, but anyway ...

If your apapche and PHP packages look like apps in your Applications folder, then just drag them to the trash.  You can also control-click (or right click) and choose "Move to Trash".  If those packages are in folders and there is an uninstall.app file, then just run that uninstall.app .

Answer (score -1):

he said, "in bash" dude;
i dont have a good solution, but you might want to search the bash command "grep" 
it searches for stuff containing strings you specify;
like i use sudo kill $(pgrep wpa_supplicant) so i dont need its PID, just the name;
then to delete in bash, use:
rm    <--is for files
rm -r <--is for folders, subfolders
example
rm -r applicationfolder
rm application
as root, obv
like the previous poster said, 9 months, this is just for posterity's sake

Comment: wth, why is this a big runon paragraph?
i guess trial and error will have to figure out how to post clearly